# Склонение названий материков с родовым словом

Tags: грамматика

Склоняются ли названия материков в сочетании со словами «континент» и «материк»? Например, "материка Южной Америки" или "материка Южная Америка". По аналогии с названиями островов, кажется, не должны склоняться. Да и названия все женского рода, а слова "материк" и "континент" – мужского. Но в интернет-источниках встречаются оба варианта, поэтому сомневаюсь.

Comment: Кстати, насчёт островов Вы неправы. Если название тоже мужского рода, то оно склоняется, напр., *на острове Буяне, на острове Валааме, к острову Мадагаскару.*

Comment: Артём Луговой, на Грамоте.ру вроде бы пишут, что по строгим нормам не склоняются, если не считать разговорной речи и художественной литературы.

Comment: Я на Грамоте конкретно про острова не нашёл, но зато там есть общий принцип: *"Географическое название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями город, село, деревня, хутор, река и др., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование".* И там же написано, что не склоняются только при разных родах (кроме городов и среднего рода). А вот в Википедии есть примеры со склоняющимися островами, хоть это и не настолько авторитетный источник.

Comment: [Здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2) ответы про названия островов, но все равно ситуацию с материками это не проясняет.

Comment: Очень странно, Элен. Грамота, как случается иногда, чудит... Не хотелось бы, чтобы это её мнение поддерживалось большинством.

Comment: Мда, нашёл ещё и здесь (http://gramma.ru/SPR/?id=3.3) то же самое (что не склоняются острова). Жалко.((

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: материка Южная Америка, на материке Южная Америка.

Обычно **не согласуются** с родовым наименованием (при его наличии) **составные топонимы**, например: в городе Старый Оскол, но: в Старом Осколе.

Сравнить также: (где?) на материке, (где?) в Южной Америке, используются разные предлоги.

Вообще говоря, географическое наименование на согласуется с родовым названием в деловых документах, географической, военной литературе, в туристических справочниках, часто в официальных сообщениях. **Это норма официально-делового, научного и административного стилей.** Однако в последнее время несклоняемость топонимов широко распространилась в СМИ, что вполне допустимо.

В то же время следует учитывать **влияние различных факторов**: род существительных, известность названия, стиль речи (нейтральный или разговорный), традиции употребления.

Мы говорим: из города Тулы, в городе Москве (русские города), в республике Индии (неофиц.), но в республике Вьетнам (иностр. топоним, разный род сущ.).

(Материал взят из книги: Бельчиков Ю.А. "Практическая стилистика современного русского языка", 2012).

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Только вот правило про составные топонимы (пример про "Старый Оскол") здесь вряд ли подходит. Евразия, например, не будет составным топонимом, но в этом случае склоняться или не склоняться должна единообразно с Южной Америкой.

Comment: Евразию тоже не стоит склонять, так как  тексты, где встречается сочетание "материк Евразия", скорее всего, относятся к научному стилю.  А в связи с общей тенденцией не склонять топонимы, наверное,  больше внимания нужно уделять вариантам, которые обычно всё-таки склоняются вопреки этой тенденции. Также можно заметить,  что  эта тема содержит, скорее, рекомендации, а не жесткие правила.